# Spring XD job deployment error

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-xd

I have observed this error multiple times, when XD shell / XD-container is unexpectedly quit and the job is still in deployed state. When xd container, and xd-shell are restarted, its not allowing us to recreate the job with the same name.

But it is not seen in the job list as well. As a workaround, we are creating the job with a new name. Is there a solution for this issue. I assumed this is happening only with XD on windows, but it seems to happen on Unix box as well.

[springXD job error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqKOQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because the job status is also saved in the zookeeper namespace, we have been able to avoid create the job with new names cleaning the zookeeper namespace where the job located.

Comment: how can I access the zookeeper namespace? I checked the zookeeper logs, but cant find the specific location where the job name is saved.

Comment: the zk namespace and the hosts should be configured in your server.yml, after connect one of them, you can list the folders and files using zk shell